# What is the best practice for using ISupportIncrementalLoading in MVVM?

Tags: listview, mvvm, scroll, win-universal-app, prism

It may sound weird and I know that using ISupportIncrementalLoading is for view layer of MVVM.

I am now refreshing my ListView's itemssource in the xaml.cs whenever the collection property updates in the ViewModel. Is there any other (and better) solution for this kind of need?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have been working with ISupportIncrementalLoading using MVVM pattern many times.

I like to create and independent Class that encapsulate all the logic to load all the data I let here an example of one of my classes I hope this helps.

I created an IncrementalCollectionBase to reuse all the code in all of my custom collections.

```
  public class IncrementalCollectionBase<T> : ObservableCollection<T>,
    ISupportIncrementalLoading,
    INotifyPropertyChanged,
    IIncrementalCollection<T>, IDisposable
{
    private long totalRecordCount;



    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public long TotalRecordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalRecordCount;
        }

        set
        {
            this.totalRecordCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TotalRecordCount"));
        }
    }

    public IncrementalCollectionBase()
    {
        this.FeedSize = 10;
    }
    public CancellationTokenSource CancelToken { get; set; }


    public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }


    private bool isLoading { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return isLoading;
        }

        set
        {
            isLoading = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsLoading"));

        }
    }

    public int FeedSize { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<LoadIncrementalCollectionChanged> OnLoadIncrementalCollectionChanged;

    public void Cancel()
    {
        try
        {
            CancelToken?.Cancel();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }

    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<T>> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void Setup(CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = null)
    {

        CancelToken = cancelToken;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            Cancel();
            Items.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

After of doing this I create my custom collection

```
    public class MyCustomEntityIncrementalCollection : IncrementalCollectionBase<CustomEntity>
{

    private ISearchentityService searchentityService = null;
    private bool searchMode = false;
    private string key = "";
    private bool IsFirstSearchResult = true;
    private IentityService entityService = null;
    private ILoginService loginService = null;
    private IToastService toastService = null;
    public MyCustomEntityIncrementalCollection(CancellationTokenSource cancelToken, int feedSize = 10)
    {
        Setup(cancelToken);
        this.FeedSize = feedSize;
        toastService = IoC.Get<IToastService>();
        searchentityService = IoC.Get<ISearchentityService>();
        loginService = IoC.Get<ILoginService>();
        entityService = IoC.Get<IentityService>();
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<CustomEntity>> Search()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsFirstSearchResult)
            {

                var result = await searchentityService.SearchAsync(key, loginService.CurrentUser.Id, CancelToken, loginService.CurrentToken.AccessToken, 1, 50);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    toastService.ShowAsync("Sin resultados", "No se han encontrado coincidencias");
                }
                PageNo = result.paging.pageNo;
                PageCount = result.paging.pageCount;
                PageSize = result.paging.pageSize;
                TotalRecordCount = result.paging.totalRecordCount;
                IsFirstSearchResult = false;
                return result.data;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = await searchentityService.SearchAsync(key, loginService.CurrentUser.Id, CancelToken, loginService.CurrentToken.AccessToken, (PageNo + 1), 50);
                PageNo = result.paging.pageNo;
                PageCount = result.paging.pageCount;
                PageSize = result.paging.pageSize;
                TotalRecordCount = result.paging.totalRecordCount;
                return result.data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
        return null;
    }

    public async Task TurnOnSearchMode( string keyword)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
            throw new Exception(" keyword is invalid");
        searchMode = true;
        key = keyword;
        IsFirstSearchResult = true;
        this.ClearItems();
        await Task.Delay(500);
       await LoadMoreItemsAsync(1);
    }
    public async Task TurnOffSearchMode()
    {

       searchMode = false;
        IsFirstSearchResult = true;
        key = "";
        this.ClearItems();
        await LoadMoreItemsAsync(1);
    }
    public override async Task<IEnumerable<CustomEntity>> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                var result = await entityService.MyEntities(CancelToken, loginService.CurrentToken.AccessToken, 1, FeedSize);
                if (result != null && result.data != null)
                {
                    PageNo = result.paging.pageNo;
                    PageCount = result.paging.pageCount;
                    PageSize = result.paging.pageSize;
                    TotalRecordCount = result.paging.totalRecordCount;
                    return result.data;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = await entityService.MyEntities(CancelToken, loginService.CurrentToken.AccessToken, (PageNo + 1), FeedSize);

                PageNo = result.paging.pageNo;
                PageCount = result.paging.pageCount;
                PageSize = result.paging.pageSize;
                TotalRecordCount = result.paging.totalRecordCount;
                return result.data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }

        return null;
    }

    public override IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(async c =>
        {
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, ( () =>
            {
                IsLoading = true;
            }));

            if (searchMode == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = await LoadDataAsync();
                    if (data != null && data.Any())
                    {

                        HasMoreItems = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HasMoreItems = false;
                    }

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, (() =>
                        {

                            foreach (var item in data)
                            {

                                this.Add(item);
                            }
                        })).AsTask().ContinueWith(z => { data = null; });

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Se ha producido un error al buscar videos");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = await Search();
                    if (data != null && data.Any())
                    {

                        HasMoreItems = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HasMoreItems = false;
                    }

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, (() =>
                        {

                            foreach (var item in data)
                            {

                                this.Add(item);
                            }
                        })).AsTask().ContinueWith(z => { data = null; });

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Se ha producido un error al buscar videos");
                }
            }

            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, ( () =>
            {
                IsLoading = false;
            }));
            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };
        });

    }


}
```

Finally I just call the initial load in my View Model in the constructor or another place.

```
 this.MyEntities = new Infrastructure.Collections.MyCustomEntityAppraisalIncrementalCollection(cancelToken, 20);

await MyEntities.LoadMoreItemsAsync(1);
```